# Java DnD : How do I get the drop target component after export is completed?

Tags: java, swing, drag-and-drop

In `canImport` function, the first parameter defines the target component. However, in `exportDone` function, the first parameter defines the source component of the `Transferable data`.

Is it possible to get the drop target component after the data has been transferred via the TransferHandler class without using the mouseRelease listener? If so, how?

Right now, in `canImport` function, I'm constantly updating a variable which contains the value of target component. It is of course, very inefficient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess there really isn't.

BUT The `importData` function does receive the drop target component like `canImport`. However, you ALSO need to rewrite how the `Transferable data` is imported into the drop target. Hence, it isn't executed AFTER export is completed. You can make it look like it does, but you need rewrite a whole load of logic.